# Node.js molude.exports return : is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, undefined, module.exports

Hi all  ( notice I am very new on Node, JavaScript and this is my 1st question on StackOverflow)

I am  getting a strange error when using module exports.

> Example applied to my test:

My main App.js :

```
     var worked = require('./cal.js'); 
     var work_form_cal ;
     work_from_cal = worked.funct1 (values);
     console.log(work_from_cal);
     work_from_cal = worked.funct2 (values);
     console.log(work_from_cal);
     .......
     work_from_cal = worked.funct6 (values);
     console.log(work_from_cal);
```

On cal.js file that have several functions to do some work on received values and then return the worked_values.

cal.js:

```
  var funct1 = function( values){
    var worked_values1;
    // do something 
    return worked_values1;
  }
  ....
  var funct6 = function( values){
    var worked_values6;
    // do something 
    return worked_values6;
  }
```

**declaring at the end of *cal.js* :**

In this form:

```
  module.exports = {
    funct1 : funct1,
    funct2 : funct2,
    funct3 : funct3,
    funct4 : funct4,
    funct5 : funct5,
    funct6 : funct6

 };
```

Running App.js : I got the problem:

> worked.funct6 is not a function

even I upper the funct6 : funct6 .

but if I set in this way:

```
    module.exports.funct1 = funct1;
    module.exports.funct2 = funct2;
    module.exports.funct3 = funct3;
    module.exports.funct4 = funct4;
    module.exports.funct5 = funct5;
    module.exports.funct6 = funct6;
```

Running App.js : run without any problens

What I missed here ?

> Note: I passed the funct6 from other file to delete it. in this file function + module.exports + require(module) was working without any problem.

Comment: Does it work if you change the export object to `"funct1" : funct1, ...`

Comment: **No**. I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that no syntax errors were made?

Comment: From I can see..no, neither VisualStudioCode  detects it. Is very strange.
On visual Studio, in App.js  on line :  " work_from_cal = worked.funct6 (values);" ,  I put the mouse over "worked " it show a window with all " exported modules" and assingments of the respective function and over "funct6 " shows the assingmens of the function.   When I start debuggins  "funct6 " show as undefined.